# Symfony5/Doctrine : Create an Entity without saving to a database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a remote third-party REST API. I'm trying to represent its data using an Entity called `Offer`, however I don't want to store it in a database.

The Offer entity should have a Repository in which I'll use `Symfony\Component\HttpClient` in order to manage data using `GET` and `POST` to the API.

If I try remove the `@ORM` annotatinos in the Entity class, I get `No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "App\Entity\Offer". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.` or `Class "App\Entity\Offer" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.` errors.

In other words, I don't want an 'Offer' table to be created after using `php bin\console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Is there a way persist entities through an API **(and not a database)** using Doctrine?

**Edit : Alternatively, how can I create an Entity linked to a Repository, without using Doctrine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But behind your API, there is no database ? Or maybe you're using ElasticSearch or solution like this ? If you have a database, you should keep Doctrine :)

However, if you really don't want it, you can do someting like this: keep your entity, remove all `@ORM\*` annotations, remove all `use Doctrine\*`, and in your repository remove `extends EntityRepository` (very important).
You can add your own abstract Repository class to extends your repositories and with a method called `getEntity()` like that : `abstract protected function getEntity()` then in your repository :

```php
protected function getEntity(): string
{
    return YourEntity::class;
}

public function foo() {
   $entityClass = $this->getEntity();
   $entity = new $entityClass();
}
```

Comment: Behind the API there is a NoSQL graph database but we'd like to have the back-office go through the API, not directly access the actual database. As I'm a beginner, I thought maybe having extends EntityRepository is important for other symfony features like forms and rendering twig templates, not just Doctrine. Thanks for your answer, I'll try creating my own Repository class.

Comment: Have you looking for a library on https://packagist.org/ who can make request to your nosql layer? Like Elastica or elasticsearch-php for ElasticSearch

Comment: I removed the `@ORM`  annotations and the `use Doctrine` but I'm still getting `Class "App\Entity\Offer" is not a valid entity or mapped super class` from symfony.. Here is how my header looks for [Entity](https://i.imgur.com/afINcZH.png) and for [Repository](https://i.imgur.com/Jfjow3O.png).. what do you think ?

Comment: Little bug on your repository: you call `parent::_construct()` but you don't have parent class :)

Comment: Just to clarify, in your original post when should the foo() function be used exactly?

Comment: When you need to get an instance of your entity class. But both method can be merged into one :)

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine is specifically built for database storage, so I don't think it's a smart idea to try and use it for storage in an external API. However if you want to do it anyway, then you'll probably have to implement a repository which makes use of the http client.

All in all I'd recommend you go for a different approach leaving an ORM out of the picture completely.

Comment: I've thought about not using Doctrine at all, but how can I create an Entity linked to a Repository without ORM? I couldn't find this information online or in the Symfony documentation

Comment: so you want a car with a full tank of gas that doesn't use the engine ?
If you don't want to store the data in the database, don't use Entities and Repositories; create custom types/classes that model your data and use them; why do you need a repository, if you don't save the data in the db?

Comment: as a beginner I thought using the provided entity / repository classes is essential for using other Symfony features, not just Doctrine. Thanks for the explainatoin, I'll try creating custom classes.